# Creating a column to identify change since last occurrence

Tags: r

I am currently developing a on going dashboard. The new feature I am attempting to add is a list of items with "flags". In order to create that list I need to manipulate the data. It a large set and I am trying to avoid for loops because it would slow down the computation time.

Currently the data is structured like this :

```
itemX,   itemY , ageOfY(a number that grows over time), Date of occurrence
```

goal is to have the Change column made:

```
X   Y   age Date    Change
X1  Y1  12  5/12/2011   NA
X1  Y2  14  5/12/2011   NA
X1  Y1  15  5/13/2011   3
X1  Y2  16  5/13/2011   2
```

note(item y is attached to item X in real life, and item x can have multiple y).

I want to create a column to store the difference of age between each occurrence of item y by date.

Any advice? I appreciate all of the help the community can provide

I Have been using the dplyr package but cant find a way to do it properly. I know mutate function would be needed.

Comment: `library(dplyr) ; df %>% group_by(X, Y) %>% mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, '%m/%d/%Y'), Change = c(NA, diff(age)))` or in base, `df$Change <- ave(df$age, df$X, df$Y, FUN = function(x){c(NA, diff(x))})`

Comment: did the trick. Thank you!